# C# Twitter to Table

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, twitter, xamarin

I have created a strongly typed class for the Twitter API, however I am having trouble placing the actual info on the Table. When I did it for Facebook or Instagram the strongly typed class usually looked like this:

```
public class IGRootObject
{
    public IGPagination pagination { get; set; }
    public IGMeta meta { get; set; }
    public List<IGDatum> data { get; set; }
}

public class IGDatum
{
    public object attribution { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public object location { get; set; }
    public IGComments comments { get; set; }
    public string filter { get; set; }
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public IGLikes likes { get; set; }
    public IGImages images { get; set; }
    public List<object> users_in_photo { get; set; }
    public IGCaption caption { get; set; }
    public bool user_has_liked { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public IGUser user { get; set; }
    public IGVideos videos { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the rootobject splits into a list for the Instagram Data, however for Twitter it only has data and there are no lists:

```
public class Entities2
{
    public Url url { get; set; }
    public Description description { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string profile_sidebar_fill_color { get; set; }
    public bool profile_background_tile { get; set; }
    public string profile_sidebar_border_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_image_url { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public bool follow_request_sent { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public bool is_translator { get; set; }
    public string profile_link_color { get; set; }
    public Entities2 entities { get; set; }
    public bool default_profile { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public bool contributors_enabled { get; set; }
    public int favourites_count { get; set; }
    public int? utc_offset { get; set; }
    public string profile_image_url_https { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int listed_count { get; set; }
    public bool profile_use_background_image { get; set; }
    public string profile_text_color { get; set; }
    public int followers_count { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public bool @protected { get; set; }
    public bool geo_enabled { get; set; }
    public bool notifications { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_color { get; set; }
    public bool verified { get; set; }
    public string time_zone { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_image_url_https { get; set; }
    public int statuses_count { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_image_url { get; set; }
    public bool default_profile_image { get; set; }
    public int friends_count { get; set; }
    public bool following { get; set; }
    public bool show_all_inline_media { get; set; }
    public string screen_name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Coordinates coordinates { get; set; }
    public bool truncated { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public bool favorited { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_user_id_str { get; set; }
    public Entities entities { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public object contributors { get; set; }
    public object id { get; set; }
    public int retweet_count { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_status_id_str { get; set; }
    public Geo geo { get; set; }
    public bool retweeted { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_user_id { get; set; }
    public Place place { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_screen_name { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_status_id { get; set; }
    public bool? possibly_sensitive { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I am usually loading my data into the TableSource class:

```
table.InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                    table.Source = new TableSource(stream);
                    ((TableSource)table.Source).facebookData = rootObject.data;
                    table.ReloadData ();
                });
```

Edit://

Here is my code for the twitter Request

```
var twitterOauthToken = twitter.Properties["oauth_token"].ToString();
var twitterOauthTokenSecret = twitter.Properties["oauth_token_secret"].ToString();
var twitterOauthConsumerKey = twitter.Properties["oauth_consumer_key"].ToString();
var twitterOauthConsumerSecret = twitter.Properties["oauth_consumer_secret"].ToString();

var request = new RestRequest("1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json");

var client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com") {
    Authenticator = RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(twitterOauthConsumerKey, twitterOauthConsumerSecret, twitterOauthToken, twitterOauthTokenSecret)
};
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Floadt.Core.Twitter.RootObject > (response.Content);
    ((TableSource) table.Source).twitterData = rootObject.data;
});
```

Comment: Which API are you using to get the Twitter data?

Comment: @Jason I am using Restsharp to create the actual request and as for creating the strongly typed class I used http://www.Json2Csharp.com

Comment: iOS has a built in Twitter API (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_the_twitter_api/).  user_timeline.json should return an array - try Deserializing to List<RootObject> instead

Comment: @jason I have deserialized Root Object but it doesn't return as a list so how would i display it onto a table view like I can do with a regular lists.

Comment: the docs for https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline clearly show it returns an array